# Can I move the linux subsystem to a different drive?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

My C: is a small solid state that's already filling up. I'd like to move WLS to my D: or E: drive. Is this possible?

I imagine I'd have to uninstall then reinstall in order to move it. I'm ok with that if it's possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with softlink and hardlinks? Windows has these to. (Aty least NTFS has them. links and junctions).

Comment: I'm familiar. A coworker mentioned linking the /opt folder to an external drive but if I could move the whole thing I'd feel better.

Comment: When I still ran windows 7 I played around with moving folders off my 80GB SSD to a storage harddisk. It has been a while but you can just move them (not copy, move seems to retain more permissions) and then create a link to them. Not as clean as a reinstall with a different path, but quick to do and works in places where you do not have an installer which grants you sufficient options.  Not at a PC where I can test that atm, so not posting it as an answer. Feel free to try it out and self answer after taking some screenshots.

Comment: WLS actually lives in a folder inside appdata, you could move that folder to another disk and create a directory junction its place.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/449 Apparently this method used to work but not anymore.

Comment: How do you create a directory junction in its place?  Can you provide evidence that this solution still works in the current build of Version 1607?

Comment: Where in appdata? What flavour of junction? Would a symlink work?

Answer (score 14):

You can move the distribution to another drive using [lxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline).

**1. Set permissions to the target folder.** First, I think you must set some permissions to the folder where the distribution will be moved. You may use `icacls <dir> /grant "<user>:(OI)(CI)(F)"` to set the proper permissions.

```
C:\> whoami
test\jaime

C:\> icacls D:\wsl /grant "jaime:(OI)(CI)(F)"
```

**2. Move the distribution.** Using `lxrunoffline move`.

```
C:\wsl> lxrunoffline move -n Ubuntu-18.04 -d d:\wsl\installed\Ubuntu-18.04
```

You may check the installation folder using

```
C:\wsl> lxrunoffline get-dir -n Ubuntu-18.04
d:\wsl\installed\Ubuntu-18.04
```

**3. Run the distribution.** after moving the distribution, you can run the distribution using `wsl` or the same `lxrunoffline`

```
C:\wsl> lxrunoffline run -n Ubuntu-18.04 -w
user@test:~$ exit
logout

C:\wsl> wsl
user@test:/mnt/c/wsl$ exit
logout
```

Answer (score 4):

```
C:\> wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
C:\> wsl.exe --export Ubuntu c:\ubuntu.tar
C:\> wsl.exe --unregister Ubuntu
C:\> wsl.exe --import Ubuntu d:\wsl\UbuntuCustom c:\ubuntu.tar
```

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51767786/856905).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, The simplest option is to move the entire application to another drive with TrustedInstaller rights. (e.g Nirsoft utility - [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advancedrun-x64.zip) ) Then create a directory link (mklink / J with TrustedInstaller rights).